# Why can the y and z-components of spin be measured simultaneously?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator

I have a gut feeling that this is wrong. By the uncertainty principle where $x,y,z$ are the $x,y,z$ components of spin $$ \sigma_{y}\sigma_{z}\geq \frac{\hbar}{2}\langle x \rangle $$
and it can be shown that $\langle x \rangle =0$. Therefore $$\sigma_{y}\sigma_{z}\geq 0 $$

Does this mean that I can know both the y and z-components of spin simultaneously? This is only true for the y and z-components; the uncertainties for the x and y pairs and z and x pairs do not give a 0 uncertainty relation. Am I interpreting this wrong?

Comment: Presumably you mean $⟨\sigma_x⟩$ instead of $⟨x⟩$?

Comment: Also, saying that something happens for the $y$ and $z$ axes but not for the $x$, $z$ pair would mean that physics looks different in different orientations - are you sure about that part? Consider in particular what the commutation relations for  $[\sigma_x,\sigma_y]$ and  $[\sigma_x,\sigma_z]$ are.

Comment: Related: [The uncertainty in angular momentum](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/210464/), [Why only 1 component of angular momentum?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/165217/). It feels like this has probably been asked on this site before, but I can't find it.

Comment: No, it's $\langle x \rangle$.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I see the problem - your notation is misleading and essentially wrong. **Never** use $x$, $y$ or $z$ for anything that's not a component of the position vector, or a related quantity - it will just confuse your audience (as it did here).  Use $L_x$, $L_y$ and $L_z$ if orbital angular momentum $S_x$, $S_y$ and $S_z$ if spin, and $J_x$, $J_y$ and $J_z$ if total (or if it might be either), and use notation $\sigma_{L_x}$ (or $\Delta L_x$) and so on for uncertainties. Here $\sigma_x$ is again easily confused with the $x$ Pauli matrix, which is not what you want.

Comment: In any case, if the linked duplicate doesn't answer your question, then you should (after correcting your notation) clarify why it doesn't help.